# How Does Catholicism Refute the Reasons Muslims Claim That Jesus Was Not Crucified?

Tags: catholicism, crucifixion, apologetics, islam

Muslims say Jesus didn't claim to be God.

My question is Twofold:

1) When a Muslim objects to the teaching that Christ was crucified, what is their given reason that anyone ever attempted to crucify Jesus?

2) What proof does the Catholic Church present to refute or nullify those reasons Muslims give that anyone tried to crucify Jesus?

Comment: IMO, why he was crucified is a separate topic and it's an excellent one.

Comment: Right. My question is not so much how to answer whether he was or not Crucified- but how to we answer their reason as to why they attempted to Crucify Jesus. So my question is really about just that topic.

Comment: It's confusing (to me) because you're bringing so many elements into the equation. (1) "Jesus wasn't subjected to Crucifixion, (2) "God made an impostor go to the cross," (3) "Jesus didn't claim to be God, (4) "if he didn't claim to be God then why does anyone ever even attempt to crucify Jesus?" (5) What is their explanation that anyone was ever crucified? (6) From the Roman Catholic...

Comment: These are entirely different questions. It's not clear what you're looking for. Also not clear when you say: ""Orthodox dogma that Christ was crucified" -you're saying it's dogmatic to believe he was crucified. I don't know if that was a mistake or what. This makes me want to ignore your question. If you think it's dogmatic to believe that Christ resurrected (that's what you're saying), then I need to back out because your premise is incorrect. I need a solid premise.

Comment: I clarified the question by removing some of the elements that are confusing.  The question in single quotes is a rhetorical one explaining my below question. It and the questions below are really asking the same thing.

Comment: Please provide a reference, or an article, or a citation for your "Muslims say" assertion so that what the actual position (allegedly) to be refuted is clearer.  Which Muslims?  Are you quoting the Koran, or a Muslim scholar's position that has become well accepted among Muslims?  There are doubtless essays or arguments on record that contain this point, and even a Muslim statement of belief on this matter.  Question would improve with that kind of support, research, and attract more and better answers.

Comment: Agree with KorvinStarmast. It's still not clear (for me). Here's why: (1) Muslims can claim all they want; it's not their religion. IMO, your first question has more weight as a Christian question, (2) "if he didn't claim to be God" is the same as #2 (it's confusing when it's repeated), (3) #1 is its own question but it doesn't need a Muslim reference. So... It sounds like you are really asking one question: (a) What is the **reason** Christ was crucified? It also sounds like there's a subtext underneath that question: (b) What is the **proof** that Christ was crucified?

Comment: You're going to have to list those "reasons." We don't know the reasons.

Comment: I don't know the reasons, that is what I am asking for. I never hear a reason given by Muslims as to why Jesus was persecuted by Jews and Romans if he never actually claimed to be God. I  was hoping someone could give me those Reasons and answers to them if they exist. Do I need to change one of the tags to apologetics?

Comment: You did a good job making it clearer  but... IMO, #1 doesn't need to be about Sunni Muslims; the question is strong enough on its own: Why do [Christians] say that Christ was crucified? ...Onto the second question: "nullify those reasons Muslims give." We don't know the reasons Muslims give; you need to provide those. Lastly, regarding the Catholic position, why does it have to be Catholic? I have no idea what the *Catholic* position is; I know what the Christian position is.

Comment: White flag. I surrender. I can't answer it the way you've got it written. Sorry.

Comment: I believe your first question / first part of your question is better asked on Islam.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. When a Muslim objects to the teaching that Christ was crucified, what is their given reason that anyone ever attempted to crucify Jesus?**

I interpret this question to mean "What does Islam teach about why the Jews wanted to crucify Jesus?" and I will attempt to address that.  If I have misinterpreted OP's intent then please let me know.

In short, the Qur'an says that the Jews wanted to kill Jesus for the same reasons they abused the prophets who preceded Him: for exposing the wickedness of the Jews and calling them to repentance.  In this, at least, the Qur'an is somewhat in agreement with the Bible.

Surah 3 (Ali 'Imran) ayah 112 says (emphasis mine):

> ضُرِبَتْ عَلَيْهِمُ الذِّلَّةُ أَيْنَ مَا ثُقِفُوا إِلَّا بِحَبْلٍ مِّنَ اللَّهِ وَحَبْلٍ مِّنَ النَّاسِ وَبَاءُوا بِغَضَبٍ مِّنَ اللَّهِ وَضُرِبَتْ عَلَيْهِمُ الْمَسْكَنَةُ ۚ ذَٰلِكَ بِأَنَّهُمْ كَانُوا يَكْفُرُونَ بِآيَاتِ اللَّهِ وَيَقْتُلُونَ الْأَنبِيَاءَ بِغَيْرِ حَقٍّ ۚ ذَٰلِكَ بِمَا عَصَوا وَّكَانُوا يَعْتَدُونَ
>
> "They have been put under humiliation [by Allah ] wherever they are overtaken, except for a covenant from Allah and a rope from the Muslims. And they have drawn upon themselves anger from Allah and have been put under destitution. **That is because they disbelieved in the verses of Allah and killed the prophets without right. That is because they disobeyed and [habitually] transgressed.**"

Surah 4 (An-Nisa) ayah 155 says (emphasis mine):

> فَبِمَا نَقْضِهِم مِّيثَاقَهُمْ وَكُفْرِهِم بِآيَاتِ اللَّهِ وَقَتْلِهِمُ الْأَنبِيَاءَ بِغَيْرِ حَقٍّ وَقَوْلِهِمْ قُلُوبُنَا غُلْفٌ ۚ بَلْ طَبَعَ اللَّهُ عَلَيْهَا بِكُفْرِهِمْ فَلَا يُؤْمِنُونَ إِلَّا قَلِيلًا
>
> **And [We cursed them] for their breaking of the covenant and their disbelief in the signs of Allah and their killing of the prophets without right and their saying, "Our hearts are wrapped".** Rather, Allah has sealed them because of their disbelief, so they believe not, except for a few.

**2. What proof does the Catholic Church present to refute or nullify those reasons Muslims give that anyone tried to crucify Jesus?**

I interpret this question to mean "What approach does the Catholic Church recommend employing to refute Islamic views of the Passion, namely that Christ was not crucified?" and I will attempt to address that.  If I have misinterpreted OP's intent then please let me know.

Paul's answer is correct in that Muslims believe that the Gospel, as it exists now, has been distorted and/or corrupted by early Christians removing important passages and adding in things that weren't true.  For this reason alone, a Muslim is highly unlikely to accept any argument based in scripture or in the Church's teaching (which is based on scripture).  Conversely, they believe that the Qur'an has been kept free of any such corruptions since it was first revealed to Muhammad.  Thus, in order for a Muslim to consider it "valid", a direct refutation of the claim that Christ did not die on the cross would need to have its basis in the Qur'an itself.  This presents a formidable task for any apologist because not only does it require them to have at least some understanding of the Qur'an -- which most Christians have probably never read -- but also functionally requires a Muslim to accept at least one of the following statements as true:

1. The Qur'an is subject to the same inaccuracies and distortions that the Bible and Torah are accused of having.
2. The Qur'an is unclear, incomplete, or self-contradictory (even after accounting for the belief that verses in the Qur'an can be "abrogated" by other verses, which is another very deep and complicated topic).
3. Muhammad did not faithfully convey the Qur'an as it was revealed to him by God; he added or omitted things as he saw fit.
4. Muhammad never received any divine revelation: the Qur'an and Islam are lies.

But their rejection of Jesus' death and resurrection goes deeper than the belief that the Bible is not an accurate record of the life and teachings of Christ.

The Qur'an explicitly denies that Jesus died on the cross in surah 4 (An-Nisa), ayat 157-158, claiming that someone else (usually believed to be one of the Disciples) was somehow made to resemble Jesus and was crucified in Christ's place:

> وَقَوْلِهِمْ إِنَّا قَتَلْنَا الْمَسِيحَ عِيسَى ابْنَ مَرْيَمَ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ وَمَا قَتَلُوهُ وَمَا صَلَبُوهُ وَلَٰكِن شُبِّهَ لَهُمْ ۚ وَإِنَّ الَّذِينَ اخْتَلَفُوا فِيهِ لَفِي شَكٍّ مِّنْهُ ۚ مَا لَهُم بِهِ مِنْ عِلْمٍ إِلَّا اتِّبَاعَ الظَّنِّ ۚ وَمَا قَتَلُوهُ يَقِينًا
>
> بَل رَّفَعَهُ اللَّهُ إِلَيْهِ ۚ وَكَانَ اللَّهُ عَزِيزًا حَكِيمًا
>
> "And [for] their saying, "Indeed, we have killed the Messiah, Jesus, the son of Mary, the messenger of Allah ." And **they did not kill him, nor did they crucify him**; but [another] was made to resemble him to them. And indeed, those who differ over it are in doubt about it. They have no knowledge of it except the following of assumption. **And they did not kill him, for certain.**"
>
> "Rather, Allah raised him to Himself. And ever is Allah Exalted in Might and Wise."

(Emphasis mine)

On a deeper level, Muslims believe that God would never allow one of His chosen messengers to be humiliated in such a way; crucifying Jesus would have been tantamount to sinful men triumphing over God (see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_view_of_Jesus%27_death#Jesus_lives) for a more detailed explanation).

**How do we refute the Qur'anic narrative that Jesus was never crucified?**

A good starting point is this:

The Qur'an says, in surah 61 (As-Saf) ayah 14 that God supported "those who believed" (i.e. as the Apostles believed) and made their belief the predominant mode of Christianity.  There is a wealth of historical evidence that belief in the Trinity **and the Resurrection** (in the form that we know those doctrines today) originated as early as 110 AD, and were formally adopted in the first Council of Nicaea in 325 AD and the First Council of Constantinople in 381 AD -- more than *two centuries* before the first verses of the Qur'an were (allegedly) revealed to Muhammad.  This is indisputable historical **fact**.

*If we accept Surah 61:14, then God explicitly claims responsibility for the dominance of Trinitarianism, which is decried throughout the Qur'an as "shirk" ("polytheism"), which God abhors!  Does this mean that God Himself intentionally and deliberately led believers astray?!*

Comment: Do they ever explain why someone tried to Crucify him? Or do they just assume its not important?

Comment: @shiningcartoonist My apologies for not addressing this in my answer.  According to surah 3 (Ali 'Imran) ayah 112 and surah 4 (An-Nisa) ayah 155, the Jews "slew the Prophets in defiance of right".  Essentially, the Qur'an says that the Jews wanted to kill Jesus for the same reasons that they abused the preceding prophets: for exposing the wickedness of the Jews and calling them to repentance. In this, at least, the Qur'an is somewhat in agreement with the Bible.

Comment: Ok. I think that is the real seed of info I was looking for. Could you maybe add that to the Answer, so its there? Thank you!

Comment: @shiningcartoonist Sure, I will update it with the appropriate citations soon.  If you are looking for Islam-focused apologetics in general, then Answering-Islam.org is the best resource I have found thus far.  One specific counterargument to the Islamic view of Jesus' crucifixion can be found at http://www.answering-islam.org/Why-not/10history.html

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the aforementioned information.  If OP wishes I can also include some thoughts on specific arguments to use, although they won't be particular to Catholic doctrine.

Comment: Sure! I would love that. You're hitting the nail on the head as far as understanding what I am asking for here. If there are no arguments particular to Catholicism in this respect, I'm fine with 'Christian'. Thank you for your updates.

Comment: Surah As-Saf is #61 not 64 and can you tell me what made you think God explicitly claims responsibility for the dominance of Trinitarianism in that verse?

Comment: @Casanova Thanks for catching that, I've edited my OP to remove the inaccuracy. As for your question, the exact text I am referring to is https://quran.com/61/14 . I am paying particular attention to the phrase "So We supported those who believed against their enemy, and they became dominant." Historical evidence shows that Trinitarianism was the accepted mainstream doctrine of Christianity in the centuries prior to Islam -- the "dominant" doctrine.

Comment: Jesus indeed was not killed by Jews who have asked Romans to break his legs so he would immediately die of suffocation, to be buried before the holidays being. Instead he addressed Ellohim-Allah(?) and breathed his last before that. https://biblehub.com/mark/15-37.htm So it can be said that "Allah raised him to Himself". And because Jews were forbidden from killing people by Romans, the crucifixion, even if it ultimately caused death, wasn't done by Jews. Thus "And they did not kill him, nor did they crucify him." - is factually correct (in regard to the Jews).

Answer (score 5):

Muslims say that Christians changed the words of Jesus over time, hence inserted false statements into the Bible where Jesus claimed to be God. (See http://www.answering-islam.org/Morin/changed.html) This claim was made long ago, before the discoveries of ancient Bible manuscripts, hymnals, fragments, the Dead Sea Scrolls and other strong evidence that no changes have been made except minor typos and a few passages that may or may not have been in the originals, none of which change any doctrines of Christianity, especially the divinity of Christ and the reality of the crucifixion and resurrection.

Some Muslims hold to the swoon theory (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swoon_hypothesis) - that Jesus was still alive when taken down from the Cross, but had passed out and looked dead. The flow of water from Jesus' side described in the Gospel of John when he was stabbed with a spear indicates that he had suffered pericardial effusion (see http://www.compellingtruth.org/blood-water-Jesus.html). You can't survive that. Such a telling detail is strong evidence of eyewitness testimony, not a later invention by someone who had never witnessed a real crucifixion.

As for why people were crucified, the Romans executed thousands of people using this method, including common criminals. Claiming to be a God might upset the Romans, who maintained that Caesar was a God.

Comment: I see. Their claim is especially confusing when i think about all the explicit and implicit things Jesus does in the personage of God. Plus the Crucifixion and the Resurrection; if you removed all those references you'd have almost nothing left- except maybe a few parables and the annunciation... which then makes no sense with what would remain.

Comment: I don't. I'm just trying to figure out why they ever came to believe that it does have standing; because it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Can you supply some links to support your claims?

Comment: Links added as requested.

Comment: Eyewitness testimony isn't always the best.  There have been many studies done on human memory.  A case in point is the World Trade Center destruction - thousands of people witnessed this event and there are many different stories of what the planes looked like and how the buildings felled.  Please consider reading "Jesus before the gospels" by Bart D. Ehrman.   The Romans believed it was okay to worship any other god, but you had to also worship the state 'approved' god(s).  Saying that there was ONE God (not worship the approved god(s)) was to break the Roman law.

Comment: Freemason: The Muslim claim I cited is more complex. Early statements in the Koran endorse the Bible as known in the time of Mohammed, but reject the wording from later times. They claim that the early Christian writings were correct, but later versions were corrupted. That is a different claim than asserting the first written copies were also in error, which is your line of reasoning.

Comment: ... Analysis of ancient manuscripts and fragments is capable of refuting that Muslim claim (which assumes the originals correct), while not capable of refuting the claim that the Apostles wrote it down wrong.

Comment: @PaulChernoch they endorsed the  Gospels and never the Bible.  Which Gospels were they talking about?  There is no proof that any Apostle wrote anything.  Your assumption is that the were written down near to the events.  Even if one year passed since they were written down, there could be errors.  If 40 years passed, there has to be errors.

Comment: @PaulChernoch my point is, if it was easy to refute the Muslim claim, they would do it themselves.  Or maybe not... if there was a way to refute a Biblical claim (let's say walking on water) would we refute it ourselves?  I "guess" the world is flat is one of the stories which many Christians believed was scriptural but then was refuted... at great expense.

Comment: My reasoning is not based on truth or proof, but on logic and consistency. If Mohammed claimed that the Gospels of his times were to be believed (even if we later found them false or made up by other people) and Muslims later said that the Christians changed the words, but we even later found manuscript evidence that such changes never occurred post-Mohammed, then they are found to contradict themselves. It is based on Mohammed's judgment of the Christian scriptures, not on their actual truth or falsehood, or authorship.

Comment: Again - there are two periods in history. Were Jesus' words changed between his death and Mohammed (period one) or between Mohammed and when his followers said that the Christians changed the Bible (period two)? The contradiction is based on period two. If Mohammed accepts the Bible as of his time in history and his followers speak of changes, changes from period one are irrelevant.

Comment: We found ancient manuscripts with those which were non-canonical (didn't want to use the trigger word, gnostic).  The Bible as we know it today is not the teachings of original Christians.  The Book of Enoch is a perfect example.  Many of the teaching in this book are applied by Christians today - but there is nothing Biblical about them.  The fall of Satan is explained in this book with more clarity than what is in the Bible.  Muslims believe that Paul made his own religion based on the scriptures and changed some of the teachings but still revere the Gospels - the question is, which Gospels?

Comment: @The Freemason, Can you clarify -what do you mean that the bible as we know it today is not the teachings of the original Christians?

Comment: The original followers of Jesus did not have have the Bible what we have today. They had different gospels to learn from. It would be blind to believe that orthodox Christianity as we know it today is the same as the rituals and practices of the followers of Jesus during and right after his death.

Answer (score 4):

For (1), you'll have to ask a question at [Islam.SE](https://islam.stackexchange.com/).

For (2), consider these paragraphs from the Catechism of the Catholic Church,

> 104 In Sacred Scripture, the Church constantly finds her nourishment and her strength, for she welcomes it not as a human word, "but as what it really is, the word of God". "In the sacred books, the Father who is in heaven comes lovingly to meet his children, and talks with them."
>
> 134 All sacred Scripture is but one book, and this one book is Christ, "because all divine Scripture speaks of Christ, and all divine Scripture is fulfilled in Christ"

These Sacred scriptures include the Gospels of Matthew, Mark, Luke, and John, which all testify that Jesus was crucified, that he died, was buried, and rose on the third day according to what he said. Numerous other passages in the New Testament echo these testimonies. Because of the principle authority of the Sacred Scriptures, that is, "the word of God", from the Catholic position no further proof is required beyond the inspired testimonies of the authors of the New Testament.

Comment: The interesting part of 134 is that it says Christ and not specifically Jesus.  The Pope being the [Vicar of Christ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicar_of_Christ) therefore is more authoritative than the Bible.  Even if there is an apparent contradiction.

Comment: @TheFreemason I don't see how your second sentence follows from your first.

Comment: Christ being a title and not a person makes it ambiguous - especially considering that the pope is the vicar of the Christ.

Comment: @Freemason what do you mean by "it"? Do you mean to clarify doctrine or are you simply musing?

Comment: I am not sure how I can make this more plainly for you.  I was pointing out a concern of the Catechism.

Comment: @Thefreemason I certainly appreciate constructive comments. If you're referring to a particular doctrine then please cite it and clearly and completely explain your concern and I'll attempt to address it or edit the answer if appropriate.

Answer (score -2):

Matthew 26:39 
And going a little farther he fell on his face and prayed, saying, “My Father, if it be possible, let this cup pass from me; nevertheless, not as I will, but as you will.”

If muslims are wrong ,why [the father] as a part of the trinity  didn"t fulfill jesus call?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack.  Please take the Tour to see how we are different to other sites: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour
Check out what makes a good supported answer for recommendations to improve your answer:  https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer

Comment: Your answer appears to be a muslim response to the criticisms leveled in the answers accepted above. You're using a verse you do not understand here, as Jesus is clearly dreading his suffering but is perfectly willing to do God the Father's will. so I'm failing to see the problem here.

Comment: Put plainly, Jesus didn't want to be spared if the God who sent Him didn't desire it. It says it in the same verse you quoted. Suggesting otherwise, as you seem to, would then mean a Muslim thinks Jesus does not want to do the will of God- which would mean he is a sinner.